# flutter remote push notification(fcm) not working IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

1. android works well

2.from firebase site to iOS real device works well (below this push to ios is ok)
[image]
3. remote push from iOS to andriod works well

4. but remote push message to iOS not working

my Xcode
[image]

my info
[image]

my Appdelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
  import Flutter
  import Firebase

   @UIApplicationMain
   @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
     override func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey:     Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
      FirebaseApp.configure() //add this before the code below

      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  launchOptions)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I had faced this issue , after long research realised that I haven't permit permission for notification, so used [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin to ask permission for remote notification .

like this:

```
Future<Map<Permission, PermissionStatus>> requestPermission() async {
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
    Permission.notification
  ].request();
  return statuses;
}
```

- Uninstall the application
- add above code
- Call this function at starting
- give permission

Comment: thank u for reply! but my status ->flutter: {Permission.notification: PermissionStatus.granted}
but not showㅠㅠ

Comment: You have to complete all the steps from https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/ carefully.